# Multivariate polynomial division using Sage

Tags: division, sage

I'm just starting to learn Sage and I'm trying to find some method to do polynomial divisions in several variables. An example of the calculations that I want to do can be the division of the polynomial `f(x)=x^2*y+x*y^2+y^2` with the polynomials `f1(x)=x*y-1` and `f2( x)=y^2-1` using lexicographic order. The result should be `f(x)=(x+y)*(x*y-1)+1*(y^2-1)+(x+y+1)`. My interest would be to have a method in Sage to find the quotients, `(x+y), (1)`, and the remainder, `(x+y+1)`. Sage has many functions for similar and more complex operations, like `reduce`, `quo_rem` or `groebner_basis()`, but I haven't found one that does what I need.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A way to obtain the result in the given sample case is as follows. Introduce the ring R = Q[x,y], and inside it build the ideal J generated by the two polynomials `f1` and `f2`. Then the "rest" above will be a representation of `f` in the quotient ring, R/J. (Ring modulo ideal.) This rest can be lifted from the quotient ring to an element `r` of R. Then the difference `f - r` is an element of the ideal, and "lifting" this element is giving the two components to be multiplied with `f1` and `f2`. Let's see:

```
R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
f = x^2*y + x*y^2 + y^2
f1 = x*y - 1
f2 = y^2 - 1
J = R.ideal([f1, f2])

Q = R.quotient(J)
r = Q(f).lift()

q1, q2 = (f - r).lift(J)
print(f'r = {r}')
print(f'q1 = {q1}')
print(f'q2 = {q2}')
```

And the above code delivers:

```
r = 2*y + 1
q1 = x*y^2 + 2*y
q2 = -x^2*y + 1
```

The question expects an `r` equal to `x + y + 1`, but observe that the difference `x - y` is in the ideal `J`, which has the following generators of the...

```
sage: J.groebner_basis()
[y^2 - 1, x - y]
```